# SQL Server Replace function #2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have approximately 1000 lines that are used to generate a db like so :

```
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,0,0,'Unknown Switch Type','Enum_CfgSwitchType')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,1,0,'Nortel Meridian 1','Enum_CfgSwitchType')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,2,0,'Rockwell Spectrum','Enum_CfgSwitchType')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,3,0,'Rockwell Galaxy','Enum_CfgSwitchType')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,4,0,'Nortel Communication Server 2000/2100','Enum_CfgSwitchType')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,5,0,'Avaya Communication Manager','Enum_CfgSwitchType')
```

Please note that i need to translate this db to french (recreation is not an option)

Here are samples of the french config file:

```
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,29,0,0,'Type de HA inconnu','CFGHTNoHAType')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,29,1,0,'Non spécifié','CFGHTColdStanby')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,29,2,0,'Reprise intermédiaire','CFGHTWarmStanby')
INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,29,3,0,'Reprise immédiate','CFGHTHotStanby')
```

I was thinking :

```
REPLACE((cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,1,0,0,'Unknown Switch Type','Enum_CfgSwitchType')),INSERT INTO cfg_locale VALUES(1,8,29,0,0,'Type de HA inconnu','CFGHTNoHAType'))
```

This obviously doesn't work (SQL NOOB)

Comment: You can try this `INSERT INTO TABLE(col1, col2) SELECT COL1, REPLACE(COL2,'x','y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update existing data you would have to do something like

```
Update cfg_locale set Field='Type de HA inconnu',Field2='CFGHTNoHAType'
Where Keyfield=xxxx
```

where could could be perhaps

```
 Where Field='Unknown Switch Type' and Field2='Enum_CfgSwitchType'
```